# Error Message When Running Monero Core GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, testnet, error-log

I created a private testnet, mined 60 blocks, and successfully transferred between two simplewallets.

I'd like to transfer from a simplewallet to the monero core gui wallet for testing purposes.

When I launch monero-core it says "Connected" under "Network status".  However, when I try to transfer from simplewallet to monero-core wallet the balance remains 0 in monero-core wallet even after 6 blocks confirmed the transaction in simplewallet.

In the terminal, it says this...

```
ERROR /home/administrator/monero-core/bitmonero/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:780 res.blocks.size() != res.output_indices.size(). THROW EXCEPTION: error::wallet_internal_error
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Wolfram Warptangent v0.10.0 release fixed this problem.

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases/tag/v0.10.0

However, I found just using the regular public testnet works better than a private testnet . It is difficult to find enough mixins in private testnet.  The minimum mixin is 4.

https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core/issues/53